# Printing #define'd constants

Tags: c, printf, c-preprocessor, constants, literals

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define UPPER   999999
#define LOWER   11111

int main(void)
{
//  Local Declarations
double price = 89.99;
char grade = 'B';
int age = 97;

//  Statements
printf("Homework 2:\n\nUsing printf\n");
printf("  age = %c, age\n");
printf("grade = %d, grade\n");
printf("price = %f, price\n\n");

printf("Using both printf and scanf\n");
printf("Enter a new value for age: ");
scanf("%d", &age);
printf("Enter a new value for grade: ");
scanf("%c", &grade);
printf("Enter a new value for price: ");
scanf("%lf", &price);

printf("Print the new values\n");
printf("  age = %d \n", age);
printf("grade = %c\n", grade);
printf("price = %lf\n\n", price);

print("\n\nPrinting two defined constants: "UPPER" and "LOWER"\n");
print("UPPER = %08d\n", UPPER);
print("LOWER = %08d\n", LOWER);



return 0;
}   //  end of main
```

Above is my programme and im supposed to fix it. I've been at it for almost 3 hours now still can figure out the problem. I've got a error and a few warnings.

```
warning: too few arguments for format
```

Several warnings for the statements in the mid body

```
error: expected ')' before numeric constant
```

this error is for printing two constants.

Comment: what is this `print()` function you're using in the last 3 lines?

Comment: Also `print("\n\nPrinting two defined constants: "UPPER" and "LOWER"\n");` is so wrong. Use `printf` and `%d` for `UPPER` and `LOWER` and pass them as param

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your printf args outside of quotes.

Current:

```
//  Statements
printf("Homework 2:\n\nUsing printf\n");
printf("  age = %c, age\n");
printf("grade = %d, grade\n");
printf("price = %f, price\n\n");
```

Should be:

```
//  Statements
printf("Homework 2:\n\nUsing printf\n");
printf("  age = %c\n", age);
printf("grade = %d\n", grade);
printf("price = %f\n\n", price);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. was just too careless. but im more concerned about the printing defined constants.

Comment: This is also bad syntax: `print("\n\nPrinting two defined constants: "UPPER" and "LOWER"\n");` needs to be `print("\n\nPrinting two defined constants: UPPER and LOWER\n");`

Comment: oh thanks. my output does not allow me to input in a new grade(char). it just skips to the next line which is price.

Comment: figured it out. to input a character i've got to use %s i guess:
`scanf("%s", &grade);`

Answer (score 10):

```
print("\n\nPrinting two defined constants: "UPPER_S" and "LOWER_S"\n");
```

would only work if `UPPER_S` and `LOWER_S` were `#define`d as:

```
#define UPPER_S  "999999"
#define LOWER_S  "11111"
```

Alternatively you could use the two following macros to "stringify" the numerical `#define`s:

```
#define _STRINGIFY(s) #s
#define STRINGIFY(s) _STRINGIFY(s)
```

and then do:

```
#define UPPER 999999
#define LOWER  11111

fputs("\n\nPrinting two defined constants: "STRINGIFY(UPPER)" and "STRINGIFY(LOWER)"\n", stdout);
```

Comment: very useful answer to a pretty terrible question - stringify has just saved my bacon in terms of getting a #define numerical value into a sscanf() format string

Comment: Oh my lordie... THANK YOU for this!! Saved my bacon as well.

Comment: TANK U SIR! =) Did not know STRINGIFY() before :-) This one works for me: 
`#define BLAH 123; 
printf("Hello world of"STRINGIFY(BLAH)" :-)");`

Answer (score 8):

I came here looking for the answer to this question and it seems most people just got hung up on syntax errors rather than caring what the actual question is. You can use printf with `#define`d values as though they are normal variables. However you must pay close attention to the type.

```
#define HEXNUM 0xA8
#define NUMBER 129
#define STRING "somestring"

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("hex number: %x\n", HEXNUM);
    printf("number: %d\n", NUMBER);
    printf("string: %s", STRING);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Things like

```
printf("grade = %d, grade\n");
```

expect an argument for '%d'. It should be in the form of

```
printf("grade = %d\n", grade);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. i need help with printing defined constants

Answer (score 0):

One method is to assign the constant defined variable value to a local variable value.  This way it will be useful in printf("%d", X); method.

However, you could use const int EXAMPLE=12, and then EXAMPLE could be used in the standard printf method, e.g. printf("%d\n", EXAMPLE);